# Combine PDF files with Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I am having a problem with the combination of several PDF files.

I am generating the PDF using PrawnPDF on the "show" action.

I would like to be able to combine multiple selected items into a single PDF.

I am trying to solve it this way using the combine_pdf geam

```
def nested_jobs_multiply_pdf
  pdf_file_paths  = params[:items]
  pdf_file_paths  = pdf_file_paths.map! do |x|
    x.to_s + ".pdf"
  end

  @pdfForms = CombinePDF.new
  pdf_file_paths.each do |x|
    @pdfForms << CombinePDF.parse(nested_job_path(x, format: "pdf"))
  end
  @pdfForms.save "combined.pdf"

  flash[:notice] = "Combined PDF successful"
  redirect_to nested_jobs_path
end
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error

```
RuntimeError in NestedJobsController#nested_jobs_multiply_pdf
Unknown PDF parsing error - malformed PDF file?

Extracted source (around line #89):
87   @pdfForms = CombinePDF.new
88    pdf_file_paths.each do |x|
89    @pdfForms << CombinePDF.parse(nested_job_path(x, format: "pdf"))
90   end
91  @pdfForms.save "combined.pdf"
92
```

Answer (score 2):

Try if this works:

```
pdf_file_paths.each do |path|
  @pdfForms << CombinePDF.load(path) #path is relative path to pdf file stored locally like path/to/801.pdf
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the following error:
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 791.pdf

Comment: You must have saved the pdf files somewhere. What's that path ?